# Work Visa for Canada

Tags: indian-citizens, canada, working-visas

I am from India, I have got a job offer from Canada and they asked me to give all my details by mail as in 
Name(s):
Date of Birth:
Gender:
Nationality:
Permanent Address:
Marital Status:
Mobile number: 
Telephone Number:
Languages Spoken:
Guardian (Parent):
Passport Number:

And they said they will give a work visa, so should I provide those details to them? and they also said it will cost 35000 Rs only. What should I do?

Comment: Who asked you to give the Details? The employer? If so that is a scam - ONLY the Canadian visa centre can give it

Comment: The amount of money requested is a suspiciously round sum, suggesting a scam intended to collect money for "fees" as well as information for identity theft. The first thing to do is to check the job offer very, very carefully, but it is unlikely to be valid.

Answer (score 3):

**This is probably a scam.**

If a company has offered you a job, they often do apply for visas on your behalf, and they would need this information. However they would virtually never ask you to pay money for it. The cost of applying for the visa is negligible compared with the other costs of bringing you to Canada.

You should at the very least check out the legitimacy of the company before doing anything. As Patricia Shanahan puts it: Does this company really exist and do the kind of business that would make them hire me, and did the offer really come from them?

- Did they interview you in person, at their office?
- Do they have a real website and a real office? Can you find the office on Google street view, with their name on it?
- Did they contact you from a company email or a free email?
- If you call the company on a number listed on the website (not one you ere given) do they know about your application?
- Are there press reports about this company showing they actually do what they claim to do?

Here are a couple of website offering advice on how to spot scams:

- [CareerMiner](http://careerminer.infomine.com/scammers-are-constantly-on-the-prowl-how-to-spot-a-scam-job-from-a-real-job/)
- [ConsumerAffairs](https://www.consumeraffairs.com/news/scam-alert-the-company-is-real-but-the-job-offer-is-fake-022015.html)

Comment: The OP needs to investigate two questions: "Does company X exist and do business that makes hiring me to work in Canada plausible?" and "Did this offer really come from company X?".